# Multivariate test where variants are not independent?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I need to test multiple variants of an an option, but I can't guarantee that the variants are independent (eg. one individual may have seen more than one variant). I also can't know which individuals saw more than one variant, nor, if two were seen, the order in which they were seen. I have a few questions:

1. Can this provide reliable results?
2. How can I estimate the minimum sample size needed for 5% significance in R?
3. If I can't possibly keep the sample sizes constant across groups, can I do any transformation on the results to adjust for this?

Edit: Adding more details. I'm testing multiple variants for an ad, but I can't be sure that any given person won't see more than one variant (I have no way of segmenting the users so that they only see one variant through the ad platform). I also don't have any way of stopping the ad campaigns at exactly X views; I'll just have to watch the campaigns in real time and attempt to pause them once they've crossed the significance threshold. My question is: can I glean meaningful results from a multivariate test under these conditions, how can I calculate the minimum sample size needed (ie. can I do a power analysis when these conditions are true), and what can I do to control for different sample sizes?

Comment: This may be hard to answer at present. Can you provide more details of your study, your data & your goals?

Comment: Added more information